# How to use Less Then or equal (<= ) in named query in xml file

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

i have used `&ls;` for  named query in .hbm.xml file but i am getting exception is `

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at $Proxy14.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1962)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2447)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2433)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2263)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2258)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1697)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:156)
    at com.sme.medialib.report.ReportDAOImpl.getAllDigAudioClipsInfo(ReportDAOImpl.java:79)
    at com.sme.medialib.report.ReportManagerImpl.getdigAudioClipsInfo(ReportManagerImpl.java:32)
    at com.sme.medialib.report.ReportManagerImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$bb345ddc.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.sme.medialib.report.ReportManagerImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$4ec4df3.getdigAudioClipsInfo(<generated>)
    at com.sme.medialib.report.ReportBatchProcess.exportToExcel(ReportBatchProcess.java:94)
    at com.sme.medialib.report.ReportBatchProcess.main(ReportBatchProcess.java:73)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:799)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1037)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:839)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1132)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3316)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3361)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    ... 27 more`
```

Please suggest how to use <= symbol in named query.

Sample Query I have written

```
select s
  from sample 
 where date &le;  sysdate + 54
 order by id;
```

Comment: Can you please show the query ?

Comment: @Suresh Plz check i have edited the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&le;` is a single symbol that in meaning might be equivalent to <=, however it is **not the same** (it is ≤). You need to use `&lt;=` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Wrap your query in a [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) like pointed in [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/hibernate-named-query-example) example.

So writing something like this:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
   ....
   <query name="yourQueryName">
           <![CDATA[select s from sample s where date <=  (sysdate + 54) order by id;]]>
   </query>
   ....
</hibernate-mapping>
```

should do the trick!

Comment: I have tried this not working <hibernate-mapping>


 <sql-query name="sql.report.getphycoverinfo">
    <![CDATA[select s
  from sample 
 where date <= sysdate + 54
 order by id;]]>
 </sql-query>
 
</hibernate-mapping>

Comment: check the sample code I provided - HQL doesn't permit select * but instead uses select s from sample s.

Comment: Yes, i did not used *, i used to get some columns.